# REACT Todo-List : How to check if an item already exist in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying a simple approach, But this approach doesn't seem to be working.

I want to check if the item exists when the button is clicked. using IF statement

```
//Adding Items on Click

 addItem = () =>
 {

    let newValue = this.state.inputValue;
    let newArray = this.state.inputArray;

    if (newValue === newArray) {
      console.log("Exist");   // this part doesnt work
    } else {
      newArray.push(newValue);  //Pushing the typed value into an array
    }
    this.setState({
      inputArray: newArray //Storing the new array into the real array
    });
    console.log(this.state.inputArray);
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function like below:

```
 addItem = () =>
    {

    let newValue = this.state.inputValue;
    let newArray = this.state.inputArray;

    if (newArray.includes(newValue)) {
      console.log("Exist");   
      return;
    } 
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      inputArray: [...previousState.inputArray, newValue]
    }, () =>  console.log(this.state.inputArray)));

  };
```

and don't push new value to state directly instead use it like below:

```
this.setState(previousState => ({
  inputArray: [...previousState.inputArray, newValue]
}, () =>  console.log(this.state.inputArray)));
```

or

```
let inputArray= [...this.state.inputArray];
inputArray.push("new value");   
this.setState({inputArray})
```